# MS Test Adapter 1.2 nuget

Tags: mstest

I have the ms test adapter added to my NuGet server repository. while ms test adapter doesn't require any dll reference how do I include ms test adapter from my local downloaded NuGet package folder? since we use our own server to store NuGet packages, I want the downloaded NuGet to be added to my test project. please help

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Visual Studio. You need to make sure your local NuGet repository is added to the list of package sources.

You can do that by going to **Tools, Options, NuGet Package Manager, Available package sources**. Just give it a name and specify the correct *Source*. This can either be a local file path, e.g. C:\Temp or a valid URL. For instance, the official nuget feed is `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`. If you're using ProGet for hosting your private repository, it's probably something like `http://bla.mydomain.com/nuget/bla`.

Then, right click on a project and select *Manage NuGet Packages*. The package manager is displayed. On the top right there's a drop down list showing you the available package sources. Make sure either *All* or your specific repository is selected. If it's not available in the drop down, something's not right. You can click the *gear icon* to go to the Options - package sources directly.

Now you should be able to browse the available packages.